Biquery - Cost data Query Optimization
I am using the BigQuery to get the cost details of GCP using the following query
SELECT
  billing_account_id,
  service.id AS service_id,
  service.description AS service_des,
  sku.id AS sku_id,
  sku.description AS sku_des,
  DATE(usage_start_time) AS usage_date,
  MIN(usage_start_time) AS first_usage_start_time,
 DATE(MAX(usage_end_time)) AS usage_end_date,
  location.location AS location,
  location.region AS region,
  location.country AS country,
  location.zone AS zone,
  MAX(export_time) AS export_time,
  CAST(invoice.month AS STRING) AS invoice_mon,  
  currency,
  currency_conversion_rate,
  cost_type,
  resource.name AS resource_name,
  resource.global_name AS res_global_name,
  SUM(usage.amount_in_pricing_units) AS usage_amount_pricing_units,
  usage.pricing_unit,
  SUM(cost) AS total_cost,  -- Assuming cost is a currency
  SUM(cost_at_list) AS total_cost_at_list, 
  transaction_type,
  seller_name,
  adjustment_info.id AS adjustment_info_id,
  adjustment_info.description AS adjustment_des,
  adjustment_info.type AS adjustment_type,
  adjustment_info.mode AS adjustment_mode,
  price.effective_price,
  price.pricing_unit_quantity,
  project.id AS project_id,
  project.number AS project_number,
  project.name AS project_name,
  SUM(IFNULL(credits.amount, 0)) AS total_credit_amount,  
  CAST(credits.type AS STRING) AS credit_type,  
  credits.full_name AS credit_full_name,
  labels,
  system_labels
FROM `TABLE_NAME`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(credits) AS credits
WHERE (cost != 0 OR credits.amount != 0) AND
  usage_start_time >= TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1714176000000) AND
  usage_end_time <= TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1714262400000)
GROUP BY
  billing_account_id,
  service.id,
  service.description,
  sku.id,
  sku.description,
  DATE(usage_start_time),
  location,  
  region,
  country,
  zone,
  invoice.month,
  currency,
  currency_conversion_rate,
  cost_type,
  resource.name,
  resource.global_name,
  usage.pricing_unit,
  transaction_type,
  seller_name,
  adjustment_info.id,
  adjustment_info.description,
  adjustment_info.type,
  adjustment_info.mode,
  price.effective_price,
  price.pricing_unit_quantity,
  project.id,
  project.number,
  project.name,
  credits.type,
  credits.full_name
ORDER BY
  usage_date

I have to do Grouping based on columns billing_account_id,service_id,sku_id,location,region,country,zone,invoice_mon,cost_type,
resource_name,adjustment_info_id,project_id,credit_id,credit_type,adjustment_type,transaction_type. Have to aggregate the usage_start_time and usage_end_time as day wise, currently
these are at hour wise.
I am passing the day start and end time in criteria.
Getting error like
"SELECT list expression references column labels which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [41:3]
"

The error message from BQ is telling you what is wrong with your query.  You must place every column from your SELECT list in the GROUP BY clause when the column is not being summed / counted or otherwise aggregated.

I understood that, but in this column labels is STRUCT type, I don't know how to group that

Does adding column “labels” to your GROUP BY not solve the issue?  In theory, if you can SELECT it, you ought to be able to GROUP BY it.  Not a BQ user, sorry.
